# I need help putting a layout feature on a landing page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im learning front end development and I am trying out challenges on front end mentor but I have hit a stag. They way I work is I put things in divs and work on them individually. I have done the top and middle part of the landing page but I don't know how to float the third section between the middle div and the floater. I have thought of using an overlay but I know don't know how to use it. Any ideas on how I can fix it are welcome.[this is a picture of the landing page i am trying to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpELu.png). The sections I need help with are with floating the div with the button over the middle div and the footer.

I have attempted using an overlay but don't really know how to use it well.

Comment: Please add enough of your code that we can reproduce the problem/state you're currently in, and ask a specific question about a particular problem. Please check out the "*[ask]*," and "*[mcve]*," guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is to essentially create an optical illusion of the overlap. Bear with me.

At first glance, the design gives us a body and a footer, and a container that's supposed to overlap the footer. Conceptually, that's fine.

If we tried to implement this literally however we'd run into a problem: we'd have to move the element down by some amount (equal to half its height), and also ensure there's enough space available at the top of the footer (again equal to half its height). That's asking us to use `position: relative` or `position: absolute` (or perhaps a negative bottom margin). Given we do not know the height of the element, creating the space available in this approach and not leaving excess space above will be difficult.

Ideally, we want the element to stay in flow and size itself like any normal element. So *actually* positioning it and moving the element about is off the table.

Instead, what we want to do is *create the illusion* of the footer extending beneath it:

- The body above is one color.
- The footer below is another color.
- We can create a gradient *behind* this element to make it appear the footer is extending upward beneath it.

If we do that, we wind up with an element that looks like this:

[image: image of the floater from the code snippet below]

Here I've surrounded the floater element with a red dashed outline, and the actual `<footer>` element with a green dashed outline. You can see the footer only begins further down, but we've created the *illusion* of it starting behind the footer with its background.

In this case, I've used a `linear-gradient` background. In other cases I might use a background image attached to the bottom of `.floater`. If there was something *really* fancy that had to happen at the top of the footer border, I'd apply `.floater { position: relative; }` and then position the fancy elements with `position: absolute; bottom: 50%;` to have them sit right on the edge, and ensure their z-index is lower than `floater-content`. The key here is it's the background that can have all the positioning tomfoolery applied to it, but the floater content itself will be kept in flow always.

```css
/* hover highlights to help you see what's going on here */
.above:hover,
.floater:hover,
footer:hover {
  outline: 1px red dashed;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

:root {
  --c-footer: #052931;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.floater {
  padding: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, var(--c-footer) 50%);
}

.floater-content {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0 0 0 / 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
}

footer {
  background: var(--c-footer);
  color: white;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="above">
    Mollit nulla exercitation dolor nulla dolore cillum et reprehenderit quis excepteur quis.
  </div>
  <div class="floater">
    <div class="floater-content">
      Laboris veniam ullamco nulla officia non anim excepteur tempor dolor proident voluptate non.
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer text
</footer>
```

**In the above code snippet, hover over an element to outline it.**